# shell program issues, exec sh script repeatedly in other sh script

Tags: shell, sh

My purpose is repeatedly execute a.sh with the input of the files.
However, after running run.sh, we can see that a.sh was executed only one time!

```
the code is as below:
        

 run.sh:
            #!/bin/bash
            echo "$$"
            for fname in "../hostchng/*"
            do
              echo $fname
              source ./a.sh $fname
            done
            
            
        a.sh:
            echo "test $1  $$"
```

Comment: If you want the `*` to expand as a glob, you should not quote it.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) will automatically detect this, saying "[SC2066](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2066): Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` does not expand as a glob when it is quoted.  So

```
for fname in "../hostchng/*"; do ... done
```

runs through the loop exactly once with `fname` set to the literal string `../hostchng/*`.  If you want to iterate over names in the directory, remove the quotes:

```
for fname in ../hostchng/*; do ... done
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that if one had a scenario where quotes were mandatory for a different part of the path, one can partially quote: `"../hostchng"/*`

Comment: @William Pursell awesome!